# iOS and OSX Helvetica Neue Issues

Tags: iwork, font

Snow Leopard came with HelveticaNeue.dfont (Truetype).
iOS5 also came with HelveticaNeue.
Presumably, a Keynote document created on the Mac, using this font and shared by iCloud to an iPhone will display the same.

But what happens if I install and use the large OpenType font HelveticaNeueLTPro from Linotype?

Conflicts? Flames?

Comment: Is it your intent to create keynote presos on the Mac using the Lino font? Will those preso be displayed through an iOS device? Or Is your concern about general effects?

Comment: The concern is: Suppose I make a Keynote on the Mac using the Linotype open font and use the regular, bold and italic weights. Is iOS smart enough to use their version of Neue, or will it default to iOS Helvetica and mess up my slides. Also, what sorts of conflicts do I get between the two fonts on the Mac. I should not delete the original, I fear.

Comment: Thanks for clarifying. Based on that, my answer is below.

Answer (score 1):

The font file does not travel with the document. There is currently no way to "load" a font onto iOS.  If you want to use a font that is not installed by Apple, your only option is to represent the text as an image.

I occassionally do this for a font-critical headline but best practice dictates use of iOS compatible fonts in Keynote presentations intended for those devices.

I wouldn't even trust that iOS would (necessarily) default to Helvetica in the scenario you present.

Answer (score 0):

I think Keynote on the iOS Device will use a default fallback if you're using a font which is not available on iOS.

Comment: …and the text layout may be altered because of the font substitution.